# rails 4 share session cross sub domains

Tags: session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

How could I share session across several subdomains in rails 4 app?

I have tried to set session config as:

```
Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_a_session', domain: :all
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `domain: :all` also add `tld_length: 2`.

Full line:

```
Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_a_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

This correctly creates cookies with an all-domain `.domain.com`, whereas with only `domain: :all` I found the cookie domain was `.subdomain.domain.com`, which is why it wasn't working.